# can i access memory mapped file through WebAssembly

Tags: webassembly, memory-mapped-files

I have multiple separate application (C++, C#) that shares data through MemoryMappedFile.
now I want to show some data from that; can I access that directly from WebAssembly???

Comment: I doubt a browser has access to your OS' _memory mapped_ file API. So WA won't have either. Since this is a yes/no question, have you found an API or code for this and if yes, did it work?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to use the WebAssembly System Interface (WASI) for this. All currently available functions are documented in the [WASI docs](https://github.com/WebAssembly/WASI/blob/main/phases/snapshot/docs.md#functions). It seems that nothing comparable to `mmap` can be found there.

Comment: Seems to be an issue opened for mmap WASI https://github.com/WebAssembly/WASI/issues/304 .